# MatMenuModule, Can't use it

Tags: angular, import, angular-material

I had a small problem with angular material that when adding the MatButtonModule api, the buttons appeared but "ugly" just by using MatMenuModule and when adding this api (MatButtonModule), they disappeared.

I tried to reinstall angular material with the server off and still nothing.

Comment: it will help if you share your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add `MatMenuModule` in you `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
   ...,
   MatMenuModule,
],
```

then for example if you have something like this in your html:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

make sure you have `mat-button` on the button to give it material style or you can define your own style.

Comment: app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],

Comment: html:
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">Above</button>
<mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>